# How to search in Gmail from a link of an email address in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, gmail, links, gmail-search

I'm creating a spreadsheet for customers and I'd like to be able to view email conversations I've had with them a little more efficiently. Right now I find the email address in the spreadsheet and then open Google sheets and search.

What I'd like is a link on my spreadsheet that opens Gmail and searches for emails automatically.

It's only a couple of steps saved but it's something I do quite frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is, actually there are several ways:

- Option 1: You could use Google Apps Script and the Gmail Service or the Gmail API. See [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets).
- Option 2: Use a Google Sheets add-on. See [Use add-ons and Apps Script](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en).
- Option 3: Use third party app. See [Account permissions](https://support.google.com/accounts/topic/7188760?hl=en).

For asking about software recommendations please checkout [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: could you point me in the direction of any of these that would do what I'm looking for? I've been searching for awhile and haven't had much luck. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @illg If you want an addon or third party app recommendation please checkout [softwarerecs.se]. Perhaps you will have luck and found a question posted by someone else already responded and if not you have the opportunity to post a question there.

Comment: I am aware that I can simply open the gmail conversation in gmail and copy the hyperlink to the spreadsheet but with hundreds of customers I'd like to find an easier way if possible.

Comment: ok thanks, i'll head over there

Answer (score 0):

If the email address is in cell B2:

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/from%3A", B2), "Read Emails")
```